# Tensorflow model in Serving mode has big memory consumption

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, tensorflow-serving

I'm load my model by code below. Looks like it loads not only matrices needed for inference, but some backward computation matrices. This model needs 4x memory than the same caffe model. Is there any way to reduce memory consumption of tf model?

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
export_dir = 'model_dir'
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph(), config=config) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], export_dir)
    tensor_input = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    tensor_input.set_shape(shape=(1,128,128,3))
    tensor_output = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
    img = np.random.rand(1,128,128,3)
    preds = sess.run(tensor_output, feed_dict = {tensor_input : img})
```

Comment: Are you using CPU or GPU? I seem to be running into the same issue. I have a model saved for TF Serving that is 200MB on disk, but when loaded by TF Serving (CPU) turns into 1.5GB of RAM. Have you found any root cause or resolution?